# Java storing both line number and value from a file

Tags: java

I have a set of data that look like this.

```
1:2:3:4:5
6:7:8:9:10
```

I have manage to use array list to store the information using a delimiter of ":". 
However i would like to store the information of their line numbers together in the array list.

```
class test
{
   String items;
   String linenumber;

}

 Example:
    test(1,1)
    test(2,1)
    test(6,2)
    test(7,2)
```

Here is my current code.

```
 Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fname));
     fileScanner.useDelimiter("\n");
     int counter = 0; String scounter;
     String test;
     String events;

     while(fileScanner.hasNext())
     {


               events = fileScanner.next();
               scounter = Integer.toString(counter); 

       Base obj = new Base(scounter, events);
           baseArrayList.add(obj);


     }

    fileScanner.close();
```

I have try using delimiter "\n" and then trying to split out the string and it is not very successful.
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
    public void Base_Seperator()
     {
    String temp, temp2;
    String[] split;
    String days, events;
    for(int i = 0; i < baseArrayList.size(); i++)
    {
       temp = baseArrayList.get(i).events;
       temp2 = baseArrayList.get(i).days;

       split = temp.split(":");


    }

  }
```

Comment: Is the number of items in each line constant? Ie. will there always be 5 elements?

Comment: There will not always be fixed 5 elements. The number of items vary i believe. However it is assume that each line will be a day. And that every item is an event.

Comment: how do you want the arraylist to look? do you want the elements of the line to be followed by the line number or are you looking for a multi-dimensional array where each line is its own sub-array?

Comment: Actually i have posted in my question test(1,1) so with events and then line number. I have a class object arraylist for storing it the problem was how to add in the line number associated with the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the code in @Alex's answer that may solve your problem, your attempt is almost close to get what you want/need. Now you only need to create `Test` instances and store them in a container, usually a `List`. I'll add the necessary code to start this from your code:

```
//it is better to return the List instead of declaring it as a static field
public List<Test> Base_Seperator() {
    //try to declare variables in the narrower scope
    //String temp, temp2;
    //String[] split;
    //String days, events;

    //this variable must be recognized in all the paths of this method
    List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for(int i = 0; i < baseArrayList.size(); i++) {
        //these variables should only work within the for statement
        String temp = baseArrayList.get(i).events;
        String temp2 = baseArrayList.get(i).days;
        String[] split = temp.split(":");
        //you have splitted the String by :
        //now you have every element between : as an item stored in split array
        //go through each one and create a new Test instance
        //first, let's create the lineNumber variable as String
        String lineNumber = Integer.toString(i+1);
        //using enhanced for to go through these elements
        for (String value : split) {
            //now, let's create Test instance
            Test test = new Test(value, lineNumber);
            //store the instance in testList
            testList.add(test);
        }
    }
    //now just return the list with the desired values
    return testList;
}
```

---

Not part of your question, but some advices:

- There are plenty other ways to write code to achieve the same solution (take [@Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23848671/1065197) as an example). I didn't posted any of them because looks like you're in learning phase, so it will be better for you to first achieve what you're looking for with your own effort (and a little of help).
- Not sure if you're doing it (or not) but you should not use raw types. This is, you should always provide a generic type when the class/interface needs it. For example, it is better to define a variable as `ArrayList<MyClass> myClassList` rather than `ArrayList myClass` so the class become parameterized and the compiler can help you to avoid problems at runtime.
- It is better to always program oriented to interfaces/abstract classes. This means, it is better to declare the variables as an interface or abstract class rather than the specific class implementation. This is the case for `ArrayList` and `List`:

  ```
  List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
  //above is better than
  ArrayList<String> stringList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```

  In case you need to use a different implementation of the interface/abstract class, you will have to change the object initialization only (hopefully).

More info:

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1065197)
- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

---

Looks like you want to store `days` instead of `lineNumber` in your `Test` instances:

```
//comment this line
//Test test = new Test(value, lineNumber);
//use this one instead
Test test = new Test(value, days);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes i have much to learn.  I will keep it in mind.

Comment: I have tried the code however it seems that it would append the line number increasingly. The reason i have thought that temp2 could store and retrieve that and match it with the items that are store with events. So with temp 1:2:3:4:5  and temp2 1 the new arraylist would store ArrayList(1,1) ArrayList(2,1)

Comment: @LennonChia check my edit. If that's not what you're looking for, then adapt the code to your exact needs.

Comment: Thank you i will take a look once i get some sleep.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have manage to get it after some modification.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to keep line number info in the `test` object because it can be inferred from the ArrayList that holds them. If you must though, it should be changed to an `int`. So,

```
class test
{
    ArrayList items<Integer>;
    int linenumber;

    public test(int line, String[] input){
        items=new ArrayList();

        linenumber=line;

        //populate with the line read by the Scanner
        for(int i=0; i<input.lenth; i++)
             items.add(Integer.parseInt(input[i]));
    }
}
```

I use an `ArrayList` inside test because you don't know how many elements you'll be handling. Moving on to the scanner

```
 Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fname));
 // fileScanner.useDelimiter("\n"); You don't need this!
 String tmp[];
 int line=0; //number of lines

 while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
     line++; 

     //this returns the entire line, that's why you don't need useDelimeter()
     //it also splits it on '.' I'm not sure if that needs to be escaped but
     //just to be sure
     tmp=fileScanner.nextLine() . split(Pattern.quote("."));  

     baseArrayList.add(new test(line, tmp));

 }

fileScanner.close();
```

Here I use `test` to store the objects you read, I'm not sure what `Base` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

A Java Bean/construct is required that will hold the day and the item together. The following code will read the text file. Each line will be converted to a List where finally the application will populate the List DayItems collection properly.

```
public class DayItem {

private int day;
private String item;

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}
public void setDay(final int day) {
    this.day = day;
}
public String getItem() {
    return item;
}
public void setItem(final String item) {
    this.item = item;
}
}
```

And main code

```
public class ReadFile {

private static final List<DayItem> dayItems = new ArrayList<DayItem>();

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

    final BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));

    int lineNumber=0;
    try
    {
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            List<String> todaysItems = Arrays.asList(currentLine.split(":"));
            addItems(todaysItems,lineNumber);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void addItems(final List<String> todaysItems,final int day){

    int listSize = todaysItems.size();
    for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++){
        String item = todaysItems.get(i);
        DayItem dayItem = new DayItem();
        dayItem.setDay(day);
        dayItem.setItem(item);
        dayItems.add(dayItem);

    }
}

   }
```